# Gravitational time dilation and neutron stars

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, time-dilation, neutron-stars

How great is the gravitational time dilation close to a neutron star? How would the effects of gravitational time dilation compare with the event horizon of a black hole?

Comment: Have you looked at [the Wikipedia entry for gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation)?

Comment: Kyle Kanos - thank you, an interesting and informative link.  But as I have neither the ability to perform the calculations nor the information to put into them, it doesn't answer my question.  I was hoping for a non-mathematical answer.  For example, I am aware that to an outside observer things crossing the event horizon of a black hole appear to freeze because time is slowed so much.  What would an outside observer see if they were watching something falling toward a neutron star in comparison to a black hole?

Comment: *..I have neither the ability to perform the calculations nor the information...* If you have a calculator, you have the ability; if you have the internet you can certainly [get the information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star#Mass_and_temperature), both of which answer the question you asked. The question it seems you *wanted* to ask appears to be *very different* than what you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

As it says in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation) referred to by Kyle, the relevant formula applicable to clocks situated in the gravitational field of a spherically symmetric object is that an observer at infinity sees a clock in the gravitational field slowed by a factor $(1 - r_s/r)^{-1/2}$, where $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius.

For a non-rotating black hole, the Schwarzschild radius marks the event horizon and at $r = r_s = 2GM/c^2$, and the time dilation becomes infinite.

Neutron stars have radii that are *at least* $\sim 1.5$  times their Schwarzschild radii, and more likely closer to 2 times as big. Thus typical time dilation factors at their surfaces are 1.7 to 1.4.

A clock falling towards a neutron star will appear to run slower as it falls inwards until it reaches these maximum dilation factors just as it hits the neutron star surface. Unlike for a black hole, an external observer will see objects hitting the neutron star surface in a finite time. This phenomenon is observed in [X-ray bursters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_burster).